# Is there a word like "stato" or 'stathole"?

Tags: nouns, slang

Recently I've heard it on BBC's Documentary podcast (What Should we Teach Our Kids?, 1:14 min into the programme).  It's described as British slang. Apparently it refers to a person who is an expert in statistics, or maybe knows a lot of facts and figures about a discipline. I've tried looking it up in online dictionaries but without success. Maybe my spelling is incorrect.

Comment: One UK jobs board lists related available jobs (in this case in Oxfordshire) with the following wording: "Statistician Statistic Job vacancies available in Oxfordshire on ... Data Analyst / Statistician / Stato / Clinical Research Statistician / Clinical ..." This strongly suggests that _stato_ is a slang/short form for _statistician_ in at least some parts of Britain.

Comment: Could you post the link, please? I imagine there is more than one recording in WSWTOK. Or provide the topic/title of discussion.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is a reference to one of the co-presenters of a no-longer-screened, but popular at the time, UK TV show called Fantasy Football League. (This is Football as in "Soccer", and Fantasy Football is a game in which players make up their own teams based on players from different real life teams and then get points each week depending on how their players fared in real life games)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy_Football_League

On the show, Angus Loughran appeared as a character always referred to as **"Statto"**, (note the double 't') who would be the show's resident expert on facts and statistics.  He wore glasses and pyjamas, and in some ways exemplified the common perception of a "geek" or "nerd".  The name Statto thus entered the popular lexicon as a name for someone who is extremely knowledgable about statistics, and I think that your quote is referencing that.

Here's a photo of Statto from the show:
[image]

Comment: This answer makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's UK slang, meaning a person who is concerned (usually obsessed!) with statistics, *especially* sports statistics, and is spelled ***statto***.

It's commonly used as a nickname. Imagine a conversation in a pub:

> Hey, Statto! What was the score in the 1961 FA Cup Final?

There's even a sports (football/soccer) website called [www.statto.com](http://www.statto.com/).

Answer (score 0):

stato-

ˈstatəʊ/

combining form

static; standing; fixed: statolith.

[from Greek statos standing, set]

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stato-

Comment: You mean *statistics*? Otherwise, what are *statics*? I've just checked with an online dictionary its meaning. Wouldn't it be better if you provided its definition and a link too? Upvote, if you do!

Comment: But I don't believe it is the right answer, still new words are always handy to learn.

Comment: combining form

static; standing; fixed: statolith.


[from Greek statos standing, set]

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stato-